# How to combine both javascripts to include ajax call for a server time instead of user time?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am struggling how to combine and make ajax call to check the server time upon loading the javascript so the time will be server time and not client time ? I just need it to call that Time.php because this page (where this javascript is located) doesn't use php and its static, so I need to do it at that way .. Would appreciate any help really!

**Ajax function to call script with time():**

```
  $.fn.jclock.getServerOffset = function(el) {
    //Want to make a synchronous call to the server to get the server time.
    $.ajax({
        url: "Time.php",
        async: false,
        context: el,
        success: function(result) {
            var serverDate = new Date(+(result) * 1000); //Convert the seconds to a number, and multiple by 1000 to get milliseconds.
            var clientDate = new Date();

            $this = $(this.context[0]);

            $this.serverOffset = clientDate - serverDate; //Set the offset between server and client.
}
});
};
```

And my countdown timer function ... so I must edit the first `new Date()` but I really have no idea. Please give me a clue how I may do it?

**Javascript for the countdown timer:**

```
<script>
var currday = new Date();
var day = currdate.getDay();
var hrs = currdate.getHours();
var hrs0 = currdate.getHours();
var hrs00 = currdate.getHours();
var mins = currdate.getMinutes();
var secs = currdate.getSeconds();
var CSWday = 7;
var CSWhrs = 19;
var FThrs1 = 6;
var FThrs2 = 14;
var FThrs3 = 22;
var BDWhrs1 = 5;
var BDWhrs2 = 11;
var BDWhrs3 = 17;
var BDWhrs4 = 23;
var FTmins1 = 59;
var FTsecs1 = 60;
var hrsOut = 0;
var hrsOut2 = 0;

var hrs1 = FThrs1 - hrs;
var hrs2 = FThrs2 - hrs;
var hrs3 = FThrs3 - hrs;

var hrs01 = BDWhrs1 - hrs0;
var hrs02 = BDWhrs2 - hrs0;
var hrs03 = BDWhrs3 - hrs0;
var hrs04 = BDWhrs4 - hrs0;

var day = CSWday - day;
var hrs001 = CSWhrs - hrs00;

if (day == 7)
    day = 0;

if ((hrs > 22) || ((hrs >= 0) && (hrs < 7)))
{
    if (hrs > 22)
        hrsOut = 7;
    else
        hrsOut = hrs1;
}
if ((hrs > 6) && (hrs < 15))
    hrsOut = hrs2;
if ((hrs > 14) && (hrs < 23))
    hrsOut = hrs3;

if ((hrs0 > 23) || ((hrs0 >= 0) && (hrs0 < 6)))
{
    if (hrs0 > 23)
        hrsOut2 = 6;
    else
        hrsOut2 = hrs01;
}
if ((hrs0 > 5) && (hrs0 < 12))
    hrsOut2 = hrs02;
if ((hrs0 > 11) && (hrs0 < 18))
    hrsOut2 = hrs03;
if ((hrs0 > 17) && (hrs0 <= 23))
    hrsOut2 = hrs04;

mins = FTmins1 - mins;
secs = FTsecs1 - secs;

var counter=setInterval(FTTimer, 1000);
var counter=setInterval(BDWTimer, 1000);
var counter=setInterval(CSWTimer, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a date string from PHP and create a Date variable like as in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_new_string)

And simply use a jQuery plugin explained at [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

It has been always good reinventing what you already have!

Cheers.

Comment: The problem is that `new Date()` shouldn't be static but upon loading the page it should grabs the server time at the moment, so I want to do that .. how to make `new Date()` getting the server time?

Comment: Yes, I also do not mean you put static date, but create date by supplying a datestring. you can get your datestring from the return of your ajax call. And I hope there will be function in PHP which will convert date object to datestring.